# Where i need put template file?

Tags: angularjs, yii, angular-ui-router

I have yii2 structure with `frontend/modules/ang/views/index.php` and `frontend/modules/ang/views/partials/part1.html`           When i write in app.js

```
.state('ang', {
    url: '/part1',
    templateUrl: 'partials/part1.html'
                   }
```

nothing happens. 
 404 error in console (chrome) when templateUrl is `'partials/part1.html'` and `'ang/partials/part1.html'`
Base href in head /

Answer (score 0):

As Angular is a SPA, all URL's are relative to the location of the index.html (or base if you have a base-tag).

This means that you properly have a folder layout something like this:

```
app/
    css/
    script/
    views/
    partials/
    index.html
```

Comment: Is it possible to divide `statics.site.com/ang/app.js` and `site.com/ang/index.php (partial/patr1.html)` ?

Comment: It is possible, but besause Angular uses AJAX-calls to fetch the templates, you putting creating a cross domain problem with that approch. But this could be fixed with CORS. But then again EVERYTHING in an Angular app would be static, also the index.html. A better approch would be to have your backend on say api.site.com or even better mapped to site.com/api